# Code a C# Windows Service or SQL Job calling C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows

Thanks in advance! I have this scenario: I need to code a service which moves files from one FTP to another. This service must be called periodically (Everyday at 18.20pm).

My question is : What is more performant or which option is a better practice? Any other alternative you recommend is also welcome !

Comment: Isn't it just a simple task to try each solution & see which has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service can work, but we can do better: you want a **Windows Scheduled Task**. This is like an SQL job, but doesn't require you to co-opt SQL Server for something outside its normal area.

Additionally, tasks like this tend to be written using scripting/automation languages like PowerShell. Don't forget to include appropriate logging/alerting.